# In what conditions can a close vote be retracted?

Tags: support, retracted-close-votes

I did not see it spelled out anywhere in the [retracted-close-votes](/questions/tagged/retracted-close-votes) tag, but it seemed as though a retraction of a close vote is always permitted, except (?) in case of the deciding final vote. Is that correct, including the case where the question has not been edited since the vote was cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A close vote can be retracted in all cases, except when the question has already been closed - in that case, your vote is already 'gone'.

Comment: Fitting username for this question!   Do I understand correctly that retraction of the final deciding close vote is impossible for a regular user, and for a moderator it zeroes the close-vote count to reopen a question (so there is no retraction as such, in that case)?  Thanks for the answer and any clarification.

Comment: In the final-vote case, the vote is just gone. It no longer exists. We switch to *reopen* mode, where users can vote to 'un-close' a question.

Comment: That resolves it.  Thanks.  I can't upvote, but will accept.

Comment: it's not just the final deciding close vote that can't be retracted. If you voted second, and three people voted after you, you can't retract that second vote any more.

Comment: @user243572 A better term than "gone" would be "cleared" (that's what close votes get marked as in the mod timeline). It still exists on the question, but it is no longer in an active state that allows retraction.